# Efficient solving of Boolean linear equations systems

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra, computational-mathematics

Let us assume that we have a collection of 1000 boolean variables: $x_1,...,x_{1000}$

From this collection we sample 10 variables $n$ times with repetition; $100<n<1000$

We construct a boolean expression $B$ by joining a `XOR` of all variables from a given sample by `AND` operators. So we have: $(S_1) AND ... AND (S_{n})$, where each $(S_i)$ may be represented as a `XOR` of 10 boolean variables. That exclusive alternative being defined in my case as: each $(S_i)$ is true if and only if exactly one boolean variable is true.

I would like to write a program which enumerates all possible combinations of values for the boolean variables that would satisfy $B$.

I am aware that the general SAT problem is NP-complete. However, special cases may be easier: XOR-SAT is in P class since it may be written as a system of linear equations modulo 2. But in that case the `XOR` is defined differently compared to my case: for XOR-SAT the `XOR` is effectively parity test (hence mod2).

I think we may construct a system of linear equations here too. Each equation would be a sum of all boolean variables and we require that each such sum equals to 1. I would implement this as a linear algebraic problem with matrices: $Ax=b$. $A$ would be also a boolean matrix with $n$ rows and 1000 columns; $x$ would have 1000 rows and 1 column (this represents the boolean variables); $b$ would have 1000 rows and 1 column totally filled with ones.

Is there any method to efficiently solve this system? I know that many standard methods do not work since they expect a system with exactly one solution. But here our domain is constrained since we operate on boolean variables. So maybe there would be a way to find out what combinations would satisfy $B$ by some clever matrix operations?

Or maybe I am completely wrong and I should approach the problem from a different angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $Ax=b$ is called a *set partitioning* or [*exact cover*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem. Each row $i$ of $A$ corresponds to an element, and each column $j$ of $A$ corresponds to a set, with $A_{ij}$ indicating whether element $i$ appears in set $j$. The binary variable $x_j$ indicates whether set $j$ is chosen. The linear system expresses that each element appears in exactly one chosen set.

You can efficiently enumerate all solutions to the exact cover problem via [Knuth's Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little the answer? Which set should I partition here? And what would be the subsets?

Comment: Your $Ax=b$ is called a set partitioning problem.  Each row $i$ of $A$ corresponds to an element, and each column $j$ of $A$ corresponds to a set, with $A_{ij}$ indicating whether element $i$ appears in set $j$.  The binary variable $x_j$ indicates whether set $j$ is chosen.  The linear system expresses that each element appears in exactly one chosen set.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Could you please include that information in the answer too, so that I can accept it?